# Realm Cocoa can't update property of realm objects

Tags: realm

I'm using Realm Cocoa and met one problem here, I can't update property of realm objects,

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

SomeObject *obj = [SomeObject objectForPrimaryKey: objectID];
if(obj){
  NSError *error;
  [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    obj.someProperty = @YES;
  } error: &error];
}
```

SomeObject is subclass of RLMObject, someProperty is a property of type RLMBool

```
NSNumber<RLMBool> *someProperty
```

I checked the error which is nil, which means the transaction was succeeded.
But someObject is never updated as expected.

I also checked the property in Realm browser, which is not updated either.(it's always false).

Please help.

Comment: What thread is this on?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, on a system global queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this question, I just found out that I accidentally Modified someProperty to @NO in another thread which may happen after the code block in the question, the code block is actually working as expected. Maybe I shouldn't suspect Realm at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You should execute the query inside the transaction block.

```
  RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

  NSError *error;
  [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    SomeObject *obj = [SomeObject objectForPrimaryKey: objectID];
    if(obj) {
        obj.someProperty = @YES;
    }
    // are you sure your object exists?
  } error: &error];
```

Comment: I am sure the object exists, and obj.someProperty = @YES is executed.

Comment: Even so, you should execute the query *inside* the transaction block. This is a common user error.

Comment: That's incorrect. It's not necessary to include queries inside write transactions in Realm Objective-C. Write transactions are only necessary when you're performing changes to a Realm object that need to be persisted to disk.

Comment: @Tim on a background thread, it's better to be certain that in the latest version after all write operations, the condition is actually true (rather than be retained to an older version where the objects don't exist yet)

Comment: Doing it inside a write transaction won't do that though. But if you're on a background thread and need to ensure the very latest changes are available, you can manually force a reload from Realm by calling `[realm refresh]` before performing a query. :) Realm write transactions are rather non-trivial operations since an open one will block any other pending transactions on other threads (including the main thread). It's best practice to minimise calling them, and to definitely minimise the amount of work being done in them. :)

Comment: @Tim hrmm while I can agree with this, any guess why you [can't do that in Realm-Java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3476)?

Comment: Sadly, I can't take a guess sorry. I work on the iOS side of Realm so I don't know a lot about the Java version's architecture.